# Unique Values in a ComboBox

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I have a ComboBox and I want it to populate unique values. I have three columns: ID | Resume | Skill.

I want the ComboBox to have Resume as the distinct value, but it is using the ID field to generate the Unique Value and duplicating the Resume field. Is there anyway to fix this?

Here is my SQL code for the ComboBox:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Skills.ID, Skills.Resume
FROM Skills;
```

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT DISTINCT Skills.Resume
FROM Skills` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for each distinct combination of id and resume... of course it's using the ID field to generate a unique value. That is exactly what you're asking it to do :-)

If you want to just select the resume, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT resume FROM skills;
```

If you want to get an id too, you need to decide on some logic like "get unique resumes and pick the max id associated with each one" and do

```
SELECT max(id), resume FROM skills GROUP BY resume;
```

In terms of choosing max or min, I'd ask if there's any need for the id to be static. Maybe this table contains resume versions, in which case max(id) ... group by resume would give you the id of the latest version of a particular resume. Then again you might want a static id that never changes... min would be a better choice if that's the case

Comment: I figured out it out by going a different route to get the information I needed filtered. I just manually created the values in the combobox and had it filter based on its value.